# App Certification WP8.1 Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, xap

I have a fully functioning app that I have tested locally on several phones. I now was ready to publish the app for a closed beta, which resulted in the `XAP` file had all kind of unsupported APIs, but when I search for them in the solution I cannot find any references.

Has somebody had experience with this?

## Snippet of Unsupported APIS

```
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=lstrcmpW. Module=api-ms-win-core-string-obsolete-l1-1-0.dll. File=vstest.exe.  
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=GetModuleFileNameW. Module=api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-1-1.dll. File=vstest.exe.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=GetModuleHandleA. Module=api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-1-1.dll. File=vstest.exe.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=LoadLibraryExW. Module=api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-1-1.dll. File=vstest.exe.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=CreateProcessW. Module=api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll. File=vstest.exe.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=GetStartupInfoW. Module=api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll. File=vstest.exe.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=WaitForSingleObject. Module=api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll. File=vstest.executionengine.WindowsPhone.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=inet_pton. Module=ws2_32.dll. File=vstest.executionengine.WindowsPhone.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=WsAcceptChannel. Module=webservices.dll. File=vstest.executionengine.WindowsPhone.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=WsAlloc. Module=webservices.dll. File=vstest.executionengine.WindowsPhone.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=WsCloseChannel. Module=webservices.dll. File=vstest.executionengine.WindowsPhone.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=WsCloseListener. Module=webservices.dll. File=vstest.executionengine.WindowsPhone.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=WsSendMessage. Module=webservices.dll. File=vstest.executionengine.WindowsPhone.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=Microsoft.Phone.Shell.CycleTileData. Module=. File=Cimbalino.Phone.Toolkit.Background.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=Microsoft.Phone.Shell.FlipTileData. Module=. File=Cimbalino.Phone.Toolkit.Background.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=Sleep. Module=api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll. File=vstest.exe.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=GetTickCount. Module=api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-2-0.dll. File=vstest.exe.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=RtlCaptureContext. Module=api-ms-win-core-rtlsupport-l1-2-0.dll. File=vstest.exe.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=RtlVirtualUnwind. Module=api-ms-win-core-rtlsupport-l1-2-0.dll. File=vstest.exe.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=SetUnhandledExceptionFilter. Module=api-ms-win-core-errorhandling-l1-1-1.dll. File=vstest.exe.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=UnhandledExceptionFilter. Module=api-ms-win-core-errorhandling-l1-1-1.dll. File=vstest.exe.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=TerminateProcess. Module=api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll. File=vstest.exe.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=_fmode.    Module=msvcrt.dll. File=vstest.exe.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=wcscat_s. Module=msvcrt.dll. File=vstest.exe.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=wcscpy_s. Module=msvcrt.dll. File=vstest.exe.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=wcslen. Module=msvcrt.dll. File=vstest.exe.File=vstest.executionengine.WindowsPhone.dll.File=vstest.executionengine.WindowsPhone.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=__dllonexit. Module=msvcrt.dll. File=vstest.executionengine.WindowsPhone.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=_amsg_exit. Module=msvcrt.dll. File=vstest.executionengine.WindowsPhone.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=_initterm. Module=msvcrt.dll. File=vstest.executionengine.WindowsPhone.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=_lock. Module=msvcrt.dll. File=vstest.executionengine.WindowsPhone.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=_onexit. Module=msvcrt.dll. File=vstest.executionengine.WindowsPhone.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=_unlock. Module=msvcrt.dll. File=vstest.executionengine.WindowsPhone.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=_vsnwprintf. Module=msvcrt.dll. File=vstest.executionengine.WindowsPhone.dll.Module=msvcrt.dll. File=vstest.executionengine.WindowsPhone.dll.
This API is not supported for this application type - Api=wcslen. Module=msvcrt.dll. File=vstest.executionengine.WindowsPhone.dll.
```

Any help to solving one could lead me to another hopefully?

**Update**
I found one reference that had one issue that I have updated and that API error was removed. But the others about vstest I do not understand ?

I have read that android has something similar that they remove before compiling. Can the issue be similar on WP ?

Comment: I'm surprised by the "vstest.exe". Is there unit tests in your app?

Comment: @kookiz My search also suggested it was unit testing. But have not been able to locate it. But we / I have not used unit testing during this development. Nevertheless how can one remove it ? My contact with Microsoft support stated that they could not help with these issues :/

Comment: Where are you getting this list of unsupported APIs? what references do you have in the project? The files listed ARE related to testing and should not be included in the XAP you submit to the store.

Comment: @MattLacey I am getting it both from the online certification and the local store certification kit. What references I have? Do you want the entire list? It is a big project using azure, c++, and many different capabilities. But if you believe the list will help I will submit this?
I know that they should not be included but we have not used unittesting, so I am going through the references to see if I can find one using them. It would just have helped if the tool specified where the testing is done, because it is not in our code. Hoped for some pointers to this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Base on [this similar thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cb5ab7c5-2cbd-4b0d-9059-14106b1a5235/wp8-suubmitting-app-xap-error-code-1028-native-api), in order to solve the above problem, please try to remove these twoo references (Microsoft Visual Studio Windows Phone Test Core and MSTest for Managed Project), after that please rebuild your project and run the Windows Phone Store Test Kit to help prepare your apps to be accepted in the Windows Phone Store.